# if using multiple IDEs do you change the key bindings?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse

I am debugging a client-server application. Client is in .NET and the server is in Java. I am using VS for for the client, Eclipse for the Server.

What do I do about the key bindings? Do I wait to get my fingers used to typing the right key on the right monitor? Or do I change one of the two to behave like the other? I am interested in knowing what others do.

I realize this is not a programming question but it is targeted at programmers, so hopefully it won't be labelled not-programming-related.

Comment: Usually it helps with writing a subjective and argumentative question like this if you make it a community wiki.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, changed it. Not that I expect to get any more opinions then what I already did.

Answer (score 1):

I learn the default key-bindings for each IDE.  That way, if I'm using another machine, I don't have to ask them to import my key-bindings.

Answer (score 0):

My own preference, for what it's worth, is IntelliJ for Java and Visual Studio with ReSharper for .NET - the majority of the key bindings, if you pick the right keyboard scheme in ReSharper, are then compatible.

So I guess the answer is yes, I make sure the key bindings are as similar as I can.